# Disable the Number to String automatic conversion in jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-databind

When I make a json request to a spring boot backend, Jackson is automatically converting numbers to strings. Is there a way to prevent that?

For example:

**JSON**

```
{
    "numberAsString": 123
}
```

**JAVA**

```
private String numberAsString;
```

after binding json value to the java field `numberAsString` is equal to `"123"`. i need to prevent this automatic conversion and need to throw some kind of a exception when this happens.

Comment: make clear whether you want to handle exception after getting request or even before getting request??

Comment: if java field's data type is String and If request contains an integer value need to throw an exception so that i can handle it using @controllerAdvice

Comment: did anyone find a way to do so?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934109/spring-boot-is-automatically-converting-interger-to-string) post gives answer to respective solution.