# Spring boot is automatically converting interger to string

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Postman, I am giving phoneId as a interger, but in javacode(using springboot), i have defined phoneId as a String. When i am hitting the request, i am getting proper response but i am expecting some error. We should handle this before controller

Postman request :

```
{
    "phoneID": 1
}
```

Java code :

```
public class Test {
    private String phoneID;
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

You could create custom deserializer and annotate your type with @JsonDeserialize annotation.

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {
    protected CustomDeserializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        JsonToken currentToken = jsonParser.getCurrentToken();
        int id = currentToken.id();
        if(id != JsonToken.VALUE_STRING.id()) {
            throw new IOException("Field value is not string json type");
        } else {
            return currentToken.asString();
        }
    }
}
```